# WPF Spin a shape. Replacement for PlaneProjection?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I had previously developed a WinRT app that allowed me to spin a shape around using PlaneProjection.

```
var spin = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames { RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(1), SpeedRatio = 1 };
        spin.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame { Value = 0, KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0) });
        spin.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame { Value = 360, KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) });

Storyboard.SetTarget(spin, shape);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(spin, "(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)");
```

I went to do something similar in a WPF app but it seems WPF doesn't have PlaneProjections?  The only other examples I have seen require a tremendous amount of code and XAML.  Is there no similar or simple way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer after much research is that there is no straight forward replacement for the PlaneProjection class in Silverlight and WinRT.  There are some individual efforts to recreate the workings of the class and hopes that it will be included in a future release.

Until then there are different ways of acheiving the same effect.  [Planerator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2007/10/26/enter-the-planerator-dead-simple-3d-in-wpf-with-a-stupid-name.aspx) is one example and [Flippable 3D List Items](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/05/17/wpf-flippable-3D-list) is another.  For more information on 3D types of effects look into the Viewport3D in WPF.